# evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^3-n^2+2n+3}{n^3+2n^2-1}\right)^{\left(\frac{8n^3-3n^2+2n-2}{10n^2+3n-1}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^3-n^2+2n+3}{n^3+2n^2-1}\right)^{\left(\frac{8n^3-3n^2+2n-2}{10n^2+3n-1}\right)}
$$

I have tried the following:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^3-n^2+2n+3}{n^3+2n^2-1}\right)^{\left(\frac{8n^3-3n^2+2n-2}{10n^2+3n-1}\right)}=\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^3}{n^3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{3}{n^3}}{1+\frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}{n^3}}\right)^{\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2}\right)\left(\frac{8n-3+\frac{2}{n}-\frac{2}{n^2}}{10+\frac{3}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}}\right)}$$

So I have a limit of $1^{\infty}$

Comment: I'd just write down $e^{-12/5}$.

Comment: Hint: try dividing the denominators into the numerators for both the base and the exponent, and proceed from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write

- $\frac{n^3-n^2+2n+3}{n^3+2n^2-1} = 1 - \underbrace{\frac{3n^2-2n-4}{n^3+2n^2-1}}_{a_n :=}$ and note that
- $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-a_n)^{\frac 1{a_n}} = \frac 1e$

Now, you need only the limit

- $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\frac{8n^3-3n^2+2n-2}{10n^2+3n-1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n^2-2n-4}{n^3+2n^2-1}\frac{8n^3-3n^2+2n-2}{10n^2+3n-1} = \frac{12}{5}$

Putting all this together you get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^3-n^2+2n+3}{n^3+2n^2-1}\right)^{\left(\frac{8n^3-3n^2+2n-2}{10n^2+3n-1}\right)} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1-a_n\right)^{\frac{1}{a_n}}\right)^{a_n\left(\frac{8n^3-3n^2+2n-2}{10n^2+3n-1}\right)}$$
$$ = \left( \frac{1}{e}\right)^{\frac{12}{5}}$$

Answer (score 4):

Write$$f(n):=\frac{n^3-n^2+2n+3}{n^3+2n_2-1}=\frac{1-\frac1n+o\left(\frac1n\right)}{1+\frac2n+o\left(\frac1n\right)}=1-\frac3n+o\left(\frac1n\right)$$and$$g(n):=\frac{8n^3-3n^2+2n-2}{10n^2+3n-1}=\frac45n+o(1)$$so$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)^{g(n)}=\exp\left(-3\cdot\frac45\right)=\exp\left(-\frac{12}{5}\right).$$

Comment: How did we get $-\frac{3}{n}$?

Comment: @newhere $\frac{1+\frac{a}{n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)}{1+\frac{b}{n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)}=1+\frac{a-b}{n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)$.